# How to avoid ambiguity in rules with optional right-hand operand?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

It's known that ANTLR4 does automatic left recursion optimization. But how to avoid ambiguity when the last operand is optional?

Giving the following simplified grammar as an example:

```
grammar Example;

root: expression EOF;

expression: binaryExpression;

binaryExpression
    : binaryExpression 'and' binaryExpression
    | binaryExpression 'or' binaryExpression
    | 'no' ID 'in' ID ('satisfies' expression)?
    | '(' expression ')'
    | OPERAND
;

OPERAND: 'true' | 'false';
ID: [a-z]+;
WS: (' ' | '\r' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

This grammar accepts both the expressions `no x in y` and `no x in y satisfies condition`. However, the optional subrule `('satisfies' expression)?` is not considered during the left refactoring. As a result, the input `no x in y satisfies true and false` is reported as an ambiguity input:

[image: 2 interpretations for the input]

The parser assumes two viable trees, `no x in y satisfies (true and false)` and `(no x in y satisfies true) and false`, but only the first should be considered a viable interpretation.

One could argue that I could rewrite the grammar as follows:

```
binaryExpression
    : binaryExpression 'and' binaryExpression
    | binaryExpression 'or' binaryExpression
    | 'no' ID 'in' ID 'satisfies' expression
    | 'no' ID 'in' ID
    | '(' expression ')'
    | OPERAND
;
```

Although it "works", in addition to the impact on performance, error reporting is no longer useful, as it is not possible to infer what comes next until the parser reaches the `ID` token.

Is there any way to refactor the grammar to explicitly specify that the expression in the RHS of the quantifier should always take precedence?

Comment: I don't think I have a ready answer for this question. Note that "How do I deal with an optional trailing clause" is essentially the same question as "How do I deal with the dangling else ambiguity", and as far as I know the best answer for ANTLR is "ignore the ambiguity report and trust the grammar to do the right thing." (I could be wrong, and I encourage you to do your own search. But that's what I've seen here, inclusive answers written by ANTLR experts.)

Comment: You could possibly try writing an unambiguous grammar based on the classic approach for resolving dangling else, which is to create two different non-terminals, one for expressions in which all the optional clauses have been filled in ("matching" or "balanced") and another for expressions which might accept an optional expression. But it's as simple for expressions as it is for statements; I've fought with this construct off and on in quite a few cases (using LALR parsers) and I think I've always ended up using an ambiguous grammar with precedence declarations.

Comment: And just for emphasis: Precedence declarations don't remove ambiguity. They resolve ambiguity in ambiguous grammars. There are a few parser generators which use declarations which look like precedence declarations to actually remove ambiguity, but they have a much more limited set of possible transformations, and afaik they don't handle the dangling else ambiguity. ANTLR takes another approach; it rewrites grammars to include semantic predicates. You can see the transformation by using the `-Xlog` command line option. (I don't know how to do it with an IDE, sorry.)

Comment: Yeah, but I always strive to resolve these ambiguities because, in my experience, it's easy to mess up with it later when the grammar needs some refactoring. In some cases, it's acceptable indeed, but for this case, I'd prefer to resolve explicitly.

Comment: but you chose to let antlr resolve the or/and ambiguity using implicit precedence rules :-) I'm sympathetic with the desire to write unambiguous grammars. I rarely use precedence declarations in production code. But there are times when disambiguation is so annoyingly detail-ridden that I don't bother.

Comment: I'll look around and see if I have a grammar which might be adaptable to ANTLR. But it was ugly even without modifications. So no promises :-)

Comment: Can't the implicit precedence handling take care here? What happens when you move the alt with the `satisfied` part up in the `binaryExpression` rule, before the left recursive alts?

Comment: @MikeLischke Although it "works", error reporting is no longer useful, as it is not possible to infer what comes next until the parser reaches the ID token.

Comment: @rici, the dangling else solution's problem is that it also error-prone: if you add a new rule to the broader rule, you've to remember to add to its narrower equivalent – a small mistake like that can introduce huge BC breaks, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: From the ANTLR book (looks like this was a goal of V4):
“The most important new feature is that ANTLR v4 gladly accepts every grammar you give it (with one exception regarding indirect left recursion, described shortly). There are no grammar conflict or ambiguity warnings as ANTLR translates your grammar to executable, human-readable parsing code. If you give your ANTLR-generated parser valid input, the parser will always recognize the input properly, no matter how complicated the grammar. Of course, it’s up to you to make sure the grammar accurately describes the language in question.”

Comment: (I know, I hate, back-to-the-drawing-board comments, but) Is this a language DSL you’re designing, or is it already specced out for you? It looks like you’re presenting a small subset for purposes of this discussion (which is nice, thank you), but every time I read one of your examples along with the “proper” interpretation, I can’t help but feel pain for anyone trying to read this and understand it correctly. (Cont..)

Comment: (Same could be said of too many ands and ors without parentheses in most languages, though). Perhaps, all this ambiguity stuff is a hint to rethink your syntax more fundamentally. If it’s meant to be written by people, and getting the parser to understand it correctly is tough, it’s likely to be “double tough” for programmers.

Comment: @MikeCargal Thanks for sharing your thoughts! This a query language designed for non-developers (although developers are also the audience). It's basically plain English, focused on short queries (less than 200 characters). For formal programming languages, I completely agree with you, but it's not the case here. The language has a particular target audience who don't see these cases as ambiguity – for them, the alternative I'm trying to disambiguate "makes no sense".

Comment: In fact, this language already exists and works pretty well. I'm working right now on evolving it to add new features/constructions.

Comment: Whew... good luck.  I do think that the “don’t worry about the ‘technical’ ambiguities as long as ANTLR builds the right tree” is good advice.  If it’s falling apart (as you try to expand it) it sounds like you may be reaching the limits of what’s practical with the current approach.